# IPAddressDeny property does NOT block connection to server

Tags: linux, firewall, services, systemd, daemon

I have set the property `IPAddressDeny` is set to `any` inside a systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sound Service
Requires=pulseaudio.socket

[Service]
# Note that notify will only work if --daemonize=no
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
Also=pulseaudio.socket
WantedBy=default.target

# /etc/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
#IPAddressAllow=10.0.1.0/24
IPAddressDeny=0.0.0.0/0
IPAccounting=yes
```

I was expecting that no connection could be made to this daemon through IP. But I actualy can, all connection are accepted. How is intended to work `systemd ressource-control`?

Comment: I'm no expert on systemd (infact I actively avoid it), but don't you need something in the original file, to tell it to 'include' the override.conf ?

Comment: @djsmiley2k No this is automatic.